# how can i get only latest email mail body using EWS

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

This is my code:

```
PropertySet itempropertyset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
itempropertyset.setRequestedBodyType(BodyType.Text); 
ItemView itemview = new ItemView(100);
itemview.setPropertySet(itempropertyset); 
SearchFilter srchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, d.parse(date));
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.findItems(folder.getId(),srchFilter,itemview)
for (Item item : results) {

ItemId itemId = item.getId();
Item itm = Item.bind(service, itemId,PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
item.load(itempropertyset);
System.out.println("item.getBody():: "+item.getBody());
}
```

**item.getBody()** printing all emails mailbody from mail chain. I want to fetch only latest one email body(top email body).

Answer (score 1):

Return all the emails you're interested in via `service.findItems` and sort them into desc order by the `getDateTimeReceived()`and get the first `EmailMessage` obj in the list?

Answer (score 0):

EWS won't do this for you as its the API its only job is to return the actual content of the body property. Because there is so much variance in what your asking (eg what happens if somebody does an inline response) you need to look at using another library to scan and detect that type of thing eg http://blog.mailgun.com/open-sourcing-our-email-signature-parsing-library/ but underlying from a technical perspective its very difficult.